# JButton Set X Location not working

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, layout-manager

I have a JWindow which has a JLabel and JButton in a JPanel. I'm trying to set the location of the JButton to the center. For some reason, setting the y location works, but the x location doesn't change.
What is wrong with my code?

```
JWindow window = new JWindow();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new OverlayLayout(panel));
    JButton singlePlayer = new JButton("Single Player", new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("ButtonSword.png")));
    singlePlayer.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(170, 50));
    singlePlayer.setLocation(window.getWidth()/2-85, window.getHeight()/2-25);
    JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("Splash.png")));
    panel.add(singlePlayer);
    panel.add(label);
    window.getContentPane().add(panel);
    window.pack();
    window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    window.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 2) One way to get images for an example, is to hot link to images seen in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556). ..

Comment: .. 3) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). 4) See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.)

Comment: Use a GridBagLayout, this centres components by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to play with the OverlayLayout, then you will also need to make sure that you use:

```
setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
setAlignmentY(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
```

for both the label and the player so that the alignments are in sync.

Comment: what if I wanted to make the button 75 pixels lower?

Comment: The OverlayLayout is not that flexible. I suggest you try using a different layout manager. For example you can set the layout manager of your JLabel and then add the JButton to the label. No need to use the OverlayLayout.

Comment: Which layout manager? I'm using overlay layout because I need to put the button over the label.

Comment: And I suggested you could set the layout manager for the label and then add the button to the label. Start with a FlowLayout. It won't do what you want but it will demonstrate the concept. Then you try different layout manager until you get the layout you want.